# WebView OverScroll

Tags: android, webview, overscroll

I'm trying to make a webView "bounce" when pulled after scroll reached the max (kind of like the "pull-to-refresh" effect).

I have my custom view extending WebView, and overriding the method

```
 @Override
protected boolean overScrollBy(final int deltaX, final int deltaY, final int scrollX, final int scrollY, final int scrollRangeX, final int scrollRangeY, final int maxOverScrollX, final int maxOverScrollY, final boolean isTouchEvent)
{
    VerticalOverScrollController.Result result = overscrollController.calcVerticalOverScroll(deltaY, scrollY);
    Log.d("overScrollBy", "scrollY " + result.scrollY + " overScrollY " + result.overScrollY);

    return super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, result.getScrollY(), scrollRangeX, scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, result.getOverScrollY(), isTouchEvent);
}
```

and *calcVerticalOverScroll* is

```
 public Result calcVerticalOverScroll(final int deltaY, final int scrollY)
{
    Result result = new Result();

    if (scrollY <= 0 && deltaY < 0)//if at top and pulling down...
    {
        result.scrollY = (maxTopOverScroll > 0) ? scrollY : 0;
        result.overScrollY = maxTopOverScroll;
    } else
    {
        result.scrollY = (maxBottomOverScroll > 0) ? scrollY : 0;
        result.overScrollY = maxBottomOverScroll;
    }

    return result;
}
```

and Result is just

```
  public static class Result
{
    int scrollY;
    int overScrollY;

    ... getters()
}
```

The thing is, **this works perfectly** on *any* view (including *webview*) **before KitKat**.

**After KitKat** this works perfectly on any view **except WebView**, where the log for *scrollY* is always 0.

Any ideas on what could have changed on this version of the WebView?

If this does not fly, any ideas on how to achieve the overScroll effect on a WebView correctly?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Android 4.4 KitKat (Android 19 )introduces a new version of [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html) that is based on Chromium. Here in this chromium browser they have removed many features from webview.

Some of these bugs have already been reported to Google. Check the [links](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62378) : [Restore scroll position feature doesn't work on KitKat](https://github.com/aarddict/android/issues/106)

From the links, this is also one of the bug reported

> On Android 4.4 KitKat, probably related to the Chromium WebView, the
>   scroll position of the previous article is not restored when you go
>   back.

This is not an exact answer for this question, but just pointing to the things. But there must be a workaround for doing this in new webview.  Let me check it and update my answer!!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [this project](https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor) may help you out. It doesn't currently support WebViews but is very easily extensible, and could solve your problem with just a few lines of code -- i.e. by implementing a proprietary over-scroll adapter to fit Web-views. Should be something like this:

```
// First, define an adapter class (this could work as-is, haven't tried it):

public class WebViewOverScrollDecorAdapter implements IOverScrollDecoratorAdapter {

    protected final WebView mWebView;

    public WebViewOverScrollDecorAdapter(WebView view) {
        mWebView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return mWebView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInAbsoluteStart() {
        return !mWebView.canScrollVertically(-1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInAbsoluteEnd() {
        return !mWebView.canScrollVertically(1);
    }
}

// Then, apply it over the web-view:

WebView webView = ...;
new VerticalOverScrollBounceEffectDecorator(new WebViewOverScrollDecorAdapter(webView));
```

If you manage to work it out please consider contributing your code to the project on GitHub.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10360944)

Comment: @ForceMagic edited to explain exactly how to use the project for Cheborra's needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Good job! :) Upvoting!

Comment: @ForceMagic Thank you :-)